# Angular Custom Form Control - Change Detection on mat-select with selectionChange event

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have custom form control with mat-select inside

I am trying to listen on change event in the parent component

But my onTouchedCallback do not work for some reason

What did I do wrong???

Thanks in advance ❤

This is my Custom form control:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => { };

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-select-form-control',
  templateUrl: './custom-select-form-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-select-form-control.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomSelectFormControlComponent),
    },
  ]
})
export class CustomSelectFormControlComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  selectedOption: String;
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;
  propagateChange = (_: any) => { };


  writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.selectedOption = val;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  get value(): String {
    return this.selectedOption;
  }

  set value(v: String) {
    if (v != undefined && v != null && v !== this.selectedOption) {
      this.selectedOption = v;

    }
  }


  selectionChange(e:any)
  {
    this.value = e.value;
    this.onChangeCallback(this.value);
  }

}
```

This is my html file:

```
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"  (selectionChange)='selectionChange($event)'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is My Parent Component Html:

```
<app-custom-select-form-control 
     (change)='customControlChangeDetection($event)'>
</app-custom-select-form-control>
```

The debugger stopped in *selectionChange* but to not reach *selectionChange* in parent controller

If I replcae the mat-select with simple input / mat-input - everything work well.

I tried also with mat-date-picker and also there the change detection is not working well

Comment: Have you seen this in angular material documentation 

stateChanges: Observable<void>
Stream that emits whenever the state of the control changes such that the parent MatFormField needs to run change detection.

Comment: Either u can subscribe to this stream and send an event to your parent or use other observable to send that event

Comment: Thanks @ DeepakJha I tried it - but it didn't help. I can send a cutom event with custom event emitter but I wonder why onChangeCallback do not reach (change) event. When I use mat-datepicker for example it works only if i write the value in the input by myself and do not select it from the picker.

Comment: In the parent controller it again do not reach the subscribe function

Comment: hang on let me write some code for you give me a moment

Comment: You need call to the function onTouchedCallBack in any time: just add in select (blur)="onTouchedCallback()" or use host https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447681/touched-untouched-not-updating-in-custom-input-component-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Write your parent component something like this,

```
<app-matchild (changeEvent)="parentMethod()"></app-matchild>
```

in component ts file write something like this,

```
  parentMethod() {
    console.log('Parent Method executed');
  }
```

Your child component like this,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Favorite food"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of ['food1', 'food2', 'food3']" [value]="food">
      {{ food }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

in your child component ts file define a method like this,

```
selectionChange(evt) {
    debugger;
    this.changeEvent.emit();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DeepakJha I've tried it and it works also for me. But it is a workaround... I do not understand, when we implement ControlValueAccessor interface and we call the onChange callback it show call the change event in the parent component... But it works only when I change input field menually... I have a complex component that has a lot of levels - I do not want to create my own event to all of them...

Comment: if you are using multiple fields i am sure you can make use of observable provided by angular forms(reactive) I am assuming you are using angular forms